# How make Show/Hide Div box by jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have five class, witch is disabled by default with style `display: none;`

Also i have div box with have this class

```
<style>.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4, .box-5 { display: none;}</style>

<div class="box-1">Name1</div><div class="box-1">Age1</div>
<div class="box-2">Name2</div><div class="box-2">Age2</div>
<div class="box-3">Name3</div><div class="box-3">Age3</div>
<div class="box-4">Name4</div><div class="box-4">Age4</div>
<div class="box-5">Name5</div><div class="box-5">Age5</div>

<div class="button-show">show</div> <div class="button-hide">hide</div>
```

bottom i have show and hide button.

I want make that in first click on `SHOW`, i can see `box-1`, in second click `box-2`... then `box-3` `box-4` `box-5` and click on `HIDE` disable box from last.

**Example 1:**

if i have see `1 2 3 4 5`, it will hide on click `5 4 3 2 1`

**Example 2:**

if i have see `1 2`, it will hide on click `2 1`.

P.S. I  want that is used `jquery.js?ver=1.12.4`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/click  https://api.jquery.com/show  https://api.jquery.com/hide  https://api.jquery.com/filter

Comment: If you have a clear understanding of the steps you want to take, then it's only a question of which methods to use.  Take some time to reference the api in regards to event handlers and dom manipulation methods

Comment: it is expected you at least attempt to do the code yourself - this is not a free code writing service

Answer (score 1):

You need jquery click event and a counter that remember the current number.

The method will be like below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let counter = 0;
  $(".button-show").on("click", function(){
    counter++;
    if(counter > $('[class*=box]').length/2){
      counter = $('[class*=box]').length/2;
    }
    $(".box-"+counter).show();
  });
  
  
  $(".button-hide").on("click", function(){
    $(".box-"+counter).hide();
    counter--;
  });
});
```

```css
.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4, .box-5 { display: none;}

.button-show, .button-hide{
  width:100px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div class="button-show">show</div> <div class="button-hide">hide</div>
<div class="box-1">Name1</div><div class="box-1">Age1</div>
<div class="box-2">Name2</div><div class="box-2">Age2</div>
<div class="box-3">Name3</div><div class="box-3">Age3</div>
<div class="box-4">Name4</div><div class="box-4">Age4</div>
<div class="box-5">Name5</div><div class="box-5">Age5</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. Cna it work with  jquery.js ver=1.12.4, not with   jquery.min.js

Comment: Yes, I have changed the Snippet to 1.12.4 version

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you could do something like this:

```
var count = 1;

function show() {
    $(".box-"+count).show();
    count++;    
}

function hide() {
    for(val = 4; val == 0; val--){
        $(".box-"+val).hide();
    }   
}
```

HTML

```
<style>.box-1, .box-2, .box-3, .box-4, .box-5 { display: none;}</style>

<div class="box-1">Name1</div><div class="box-1">Age1</div>
<div class="box-2">Name2</div><div class="box-2">Age2</div>
<div class="box-3">Name3</div><div class="box-3">Age3</div>
<div class="box-4">Name4</div><div class="box-4">Age4</div>
<div class="box-5">Name5</div><div class="box-5">Age5</div>

<div class="button-show" onclick="show()">show</div> <div class="button-hide" onclick="hide()">hide</div>
```

Comment: I try but it is not working, please give full example